# Adding double to double in a more fixed way?

Tags: c++

I'm using double instead of float in my code but unfortunately i faced the next problem :
When i try to add :

```
1.000000000000020206059048177849 + 0.000000000000020206059048177849
```

i have this result :

```
1.000000000000040400000000000000
```

which avoid the last 14 number.. i want the result to be more accurate.
i know this might look silly but really this is so important to me .. anyone can help?

here's a simple code example  :

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
  double a=1.000000000000020206059048177849 + 0.000000000000020206059048177849;
  cout<<fixed<<setprecision(30)<<a;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [floating point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If you want to have more accuracy, you need to use another type, for example gmplib (`mpf_class`).

Comment: What computer/compiler are you using? I'm on mac with Intel i5 (64 bit) and using clang LLVM compiler 5.1, and I'm getting correct result - `1.000000000000040412118096355698`

Comment: Hm, g++ yields the same result: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b551f1e80146f063

Comment: I'm using devc++ and my computer is 64 bit

Comment: Works fine for me on Linux.  What happens if you use `printf("%.30f\n", a);` instead?

Comment: DevC++ is not a compiler but an IDE. You have to find out which compiler you installed with DevC++ and possibly upgrade.

Comment: Minor warning regarding some comments here: Compilers may use higher precision during compile time. If this works fine for some people, there compiler may simple use e.g. GMP for evaluation. Updating your compiler won't help if these results are computed during run-time. If these are static results indeed, you are better of by using some computer algebra system, e.g. Maple, to compute the precise results and copy them to your program.

Comment: @MarkusMayr: That's almost definitely not what's happening here.  And gcc uses mpfr to do floating-point constant folding carefully; what's almost certainly happening here is silly roundoff on output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update:* The answer below assumes that the expression is evaluated during run-time, i.e. you are not adding compile-time constants. This is not necessarily true, your compiler may evaluate the expression during compile time. It may use higher precision for this. As suggested in the comments, the way you print out the number might be the root cause for your problem.

---

If you absolutly need more precision and can't make any other twists, your only option is to increase precision. `double` values provide a precision of about 16 decimal digits. You have the following options:

- Use a library that provides higher precision by implementing floating point operations in software. This is slow, but you can get as precise as you want to, see e.g. GMP, the GNU Multiple Precision Library.
- The other option is to use a `long double`, which is at least as precise as `double`. On some platforms, `long double` may even provide more precision than a `double`, but in general it does not. On your typical desktop PC it may be `80` bits long (compared to `64` bits), but this is not necessarily true and depends on your platform and your compiler. It is not portable.

Maybe, you can avoid the hassle and tune your implementation a bit in order to avoid floating point errors. Can you reorder operations? Your intermediate results are of the form `1+x`. Is there a way to compute `x` instead of `1+x`? Subtracting `1` is not an option here, of course, because then precision of `x` is already lost.